# Hide Table in Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a series of Tables in a Word document that depending on the situation may need to be filled out. To make the document look clean, I want to allow users to use a check-box to determine if the associated table is relevant or not. On a click of the check-box, the entire table should disappear. I've looked at some solutions available, but none provide consistent results.

I've tried the following:

```
Sub Hide()

With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Test").Range.Tables(1).Range.Font
    If .Hidden = True Then
        .Hidden = False
        Else
        .Hidden = True
   End If
End With
End Sub
```

I assign the "Test" value to the Table in question. When I run the macro, the Table will disappear.

However, the next step is have the table disappear when clicking the Content Control Check-box. I am not sure how to structure that

Comment: If the table disappears in Print Preview you likely have Show Hidden Text checked under options. Alternatively, the bookmarked range may not include the table. If you type `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bookmark").Range.Select` in the Immediate window the entire table should be selected. If it isn't you need to select the entire table before you insert the bookmark.

Comment: I think the problem is that when I add the Content Control, it is not being recognized by the VBA code. CheckBox1 is undefined

Comment: Hiding the table's fonts does not hide the table... You could put the table inside a textbox and hide the textbox's anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much playing around, I got it to work. Posting for others that may want to use this functionality:

```
Private Sub Test_Checkbox_Click()

If Test_Checkbox.Value = True Then

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Test_table").Range.Tables(1).Range.Font.Hidden = True

Else

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Test_table").Range.Tables(1).Range.Font.Hidden = False

End If

End Sub
```

Make sure to use ActiveX Checkbox controls. I used this code several times throughout my Word template and just assigned several different bookmarks